# Efficient method for Iterating over rows and replace by get column method in a data table?

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to iterate every rows and calculate Value from Columns A to E and corresponding column name from WhichCol. It works, but this step takes so long for 50,000 rows data. Is there an efficient way to do this?

```
library(data.table)
df<-structure(list(Id = 1:10, A = c(73L, 61L, 46L, 26L, 18L, 29L, 
              88L, 18L, 56L, 81L), B = c(68L, 49L, 27L, 10L, 37L, 72L, 71L, 
              60L, 52L, 62L), C = c(98L, 59L, 76L, 46L, 46L, 31L, 77L, 83L, 
              51L, 6L), D = c(40L, 18L, 27L, 18L, 72L, 95L, 87L, 29L, 35L, 
              80L), E = c(74L, 87L, 27L, 98L, 54L, 91L, 100L, 71L, 13L, 15L
              ), WhichCol = c("A", "C", "E", "B", "A", "D", "A", "C", "E", 
              "B"), Value = c(73L, 59L, 27L, 10L, 18L, 95L, 88L, 83L, 13L, 
              62L)), .Names = c("Id", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "WhichCol", 
              "Value"), class = "data.frame")

setDT(df)
df[["Value"]]<-sapply(1:nrow(df), function(x){ df[x, get(WhichCol)] })
```

Value column is added in the sample data here - but that's what I am trying to get..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could instead of looping over each row, use the fact, that for each value of `WhichCol` you know which colum you want. (e.g. for every `WhichCol == "A"` take column `A`).

`df[, ValueNew := get(unique(WhichCol)), by = WhichCol]`

I did a little speed test:

```
 n <- 1000
 df <- rbindlist(rep(list(df), n))

 # over unique WhichCol

 system.time(df[, ValueNew := get(unique(WhichCol)), by = WhichCol])
    user  system elapsed 
   0.002   0.000   0.001 

 system.time(df[["Value2"]]<-sapply(1:nrow(df), function(x){ df[x, get(WhichCol)] }))
   user  system elapsed 
  5.445   0.021   5.472
```

I hope this will help you.